# C#, fontdialog doesn't show up on windows XP

Tags: c#

I have a weird problem.

I am developing an application where the user can select a font from a fontdialog by clicking on a button.

The problem is when running on win XP the fontdialog doesn't show up. If I press ALT key it shows up (after I click on the font button).

I searched web for a solution and found a guy with similar problem and his quick solution was programmatically press ALT. Of course, how could I press ALT during/after fontdialog.ShowDialog()? It's not really clean, thought.

Thanks for any advice.

Petr

Comment: Please show the code that displays the dialog font

Comment: Comment out the form's Paint event or OnPaint override and try again.

Comment: Nothing special about the code, it works perfectly on vista and W7:

Comment: int index = Convert.ToInt32(cboxPart.SelectedValue);

                if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    main.segmentsSaved.Where(a => a.ID == index).Select(a => { a.Font = fontDialog1.Font; return a; }).ToList();
                }

Comment: I thought it would be something with the paint or refresh but cannot find what.

Comment: There is no Paint() nor OnPaint override on this form.

Answer (score 0):

[resolved]

I had the buttons and stuff on a tabpage.
And in it's paint method I had something which didn't belonged there. After I commented it out, it works!

Thanks

Petr